# Run Time Error 13: Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am having a problem with the following code and am getting a type mismatch error on the bolded line of code:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Dim p
     Dim ActivePrinter
     Dim Sheets

     p = Application.ActivePrinter
     ActivePrinter = ("Send to OneNote 2010")

     **Sheets(Array("R-Overview", "R-Savings", "R-Table")).PrintOut , , 1**

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create/pass the array like this. Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim p
    Dim ActivePrinter
    Dim shtsArray(1 To 3) As String

    p = Application.ActivePrinter
    ActivePrinter = ("Send to OneNote 2010")

    shtsArray(1) = "R-Overview"
    shtsArray(2) = "R-Savings"
    shtsArray(3) = "R-Table"

    Sheets(shtsArray).PrintOut , , 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**ONE MORE WAY**

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim p
    Dim ActivePrinter
    Dim shtsArray
    Dim sheetNames As String

    p = Application.ActivePrinter
    ActivePrinter = ("Send to OneNote 2010")

    sheetNames = "R-Overview,R-Savings,R-Table"
    shtsArray = Split(sheetNames, ",")

    Sheets(shtsArray).PrintOut , , 1
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a "Run-Time error '1004': Application Defined or object defined error" on the second to last line.

Comment: I am getting the error on the "sheets(shtsArray).PrintOut,,1" Line

Comment: I dont know what was wrong with my worksheet byt I just closed out of excel and went back in and now it works fine ??? thank you for the quick response

Comment: Glad it's all sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549388/pdf-print-out-code) your code is working.

You get Type Mismatch error in the modified code because `Sheets` variable is declared as variant. Simply remove it and your code will work again.